# How to make a drop-in datagridview toolclass that handles the rows clear command without rewrting a complete datagridview

Tags: vb.net, class, datagridview

My goal is to make a custom datagridview with a filterrow, as a drop-in for all datagridviews which I have in my program(s). For this, all normal commands should still work but to some commands, additional coding is necesaary. To add a row after the rows.clear command, I need to override the rows.clear command which is not overridable.

So to try to do it, i made the following solution:

```
Public Class dgv_with_filterrow
Inherits DataGridView
Private customRows As New CustomDataGridViewRowCollection(Me)

Public Shadows ReadOnly Property Rows As CustomDataGridViewRowCollection
    Get
        Return customRows
    End Get
End Property

Public Overrides Sub Refresh()
    ' Add your custom implementation here
    Console.WriteLine("Custom Refresh() method called")

    ' Call the base class implementation
    MyBase.Refresh()
End Sub

' Add other overridden methods as needed

Public Class CustomDataGridViewRowCollection
    Inherits DataGridViewRowCollection

    Public Sub New(ByVal dataGridView As DataGridView)
        MyBase.New(dataGridView)
    End Sub

    ' Override the Clear method to provide custom behavior
    Public Overrides Sub Clear()
        ' Your custom implementation goes here
        Console.WriteLine("Custom Rows.Clear() method called")

        ' Call the base class implementation
        MyBase.Clear()
    End Sub
End Class
```

End Class`

The problem is that with this code, for example the rows.add statement also does not work and probably the rest of the row commands.. To completely catch all row commands etc looks a little bit strange/ overdone.....

Isn't there a way to add script to the rows clear command and not have to catch all row commands to make sure the datagridview still works as usual.. Just add a bit of script after the row clear command..

I know I can also add on the base level a Rowsclear command which shadows the rows.clear but then it is not a drop-in solution and I have to make sure that everywhere a rows.clear command is used,another command (rowsclear) is used....

Anybody some good ideas to make a real drop-in solution that adds some script to rows.clear to add back the filterrow?

Comment: Bind the grid to a data source that supports filtering. `DataTable`, `DataView`, `BindingSource` ... Then you just need to set the filter text. Or bind it to list of models (`List<T>`, `BindingList<T>` ...) and execute LINQ queries to bind filtered collections. Find examples in SO about that and no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I was actually making this for my unbound datagridviews.... Besides bound dgv, it is sometimes a lot easier to use unbound versions, so I have a bunch of them.
And I do not ask help for fitering, that is not the problem. The problem is catching the rows.clear command in making a drop-in solution...